# How to transfer a chart to a Microsoft word document

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ms-word

My overall task is to make a report page on `Microsoft word`.

The way this is going to work is a by a user choosing a date, a combo box item and then clicking a button on a form.

The word document will auto generate and populate with data from `SQL`.

I have made a chart in `VB.Net` and need to transfer it to a `MS-Word` document, either by turning it to an image or creating the graph on word. I've had a look all over and I can't find any advice or walk throughs on this subject. I have included a picture of what the graph would look like.

Any help would be appreciated. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After read this : [How to Insert picture in word Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb497430(v=office.15).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#Anchor_3), you just need to save you graph as a image an after that use this sample to add your picture in your document.

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what i was looking for